# Tools to monitor infrastructure: see CPU and RAM usages per IIS applications on a dashboard

Tags: iis, cpu, monitoring, ram, infrastructure

I'm trying to list all the tools that could help me to monitor my infrastructure.

It is composed of servers with severals IIS applications.

My first goal is to be able to consult a dashboard from where I could read CPU and RAM usages per server and per application. Bandwith would be interesting too.

I just discovered [Nagios](http://www.nagios.org/), but I'm sure there are many other great tools.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Are you considering commercial tools as well?

Comment: Yes, I just want to find the best tools that exist. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind commercial tools, [Datadog](http://www.datadoghq.com/) can monitor IIS (and more).

*Disclaimer: I work for them*

Comment: Thank you, that's interesting!